# Evaluate $\sum_{k=2}^\infty{\frac{(-1)^k}{\ln k}}$

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, summation, special-functions

I'm wondering if there is an exact solution of
$$S=\sum_{k=2}^\infty{\frac{(-1)^k}{\ln k}}$$
I let $$S(x)=\sum_{k=2}^\infty{\frac{(-1)^kk^x}{\ln k}}$$
So$$S'(x)=\sum_{k=2}^\infty{(-1)^kk^x}=1+(2^{x+1}-1)\zeta(-x)$$
and $S(-\infty)=0$
Then I can get$$S=S(0)=\int_{-\infty}^0{1+(2^{x+1}-1)\zeta(-x)dx}$$
I have no idea about the integral.

Comment: First of all change $-x$ on $x$. And consider "globally convergent series" https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_zeta_function . It may help you.

Comment: Your integral reminds me of the [Dirichlet Eta function](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/DirichletEtaFunction.html) in terms of the Riemann Zeta function.

Answer (score 2):

The given series is convergent by Leibniz' test, but in order to compute an accurate numerical approximation of it we need to accelerate the convergence of its partial sums, since $\log k$ diverges quite slowly. A first simple manipulation is
$$ \sum_{k\geq 2}\frac{(-1)^k}{\log k} = \sum_{n\geq 1}\left(\frac{1}{\log(2n)}-\frac{1}{\log(2n+1)}\right)=\sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{\log\left(1+\frac{1}{2n}\right)}{\log(2n)\log(2n+1)} $$
where the main term of the RHS now behaves like $\frac{1}{2n\log^2(2n)}$. Still unsatisfactory, but this is approximately $\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{1}{\log(2n)}-\frac{1}{\log(2n+2)}\right)$, so by creative telescoping
$$ \sum_{k\geq 2}\frac{(-1)^k}{\log k}=\frac{1}{2\log 2}+\frac{1}{2}\sum_{n\geq 1}\left[\frac{1}{\log(2n)}-\frac{2}{\log(2n+1)}+\frac{1}{\log(2n+2)}\right] $$
where the main term of the last series behaves like $\frac{1}{4n^2\log^2(n)}$. The next step is to approximate $\frac{1}{2}\left[\frac{1}{\log(2n)}-\frac{2}{\log(2n+1)}+\frac{1}{\log(2n+2)}\right]$ with $\frac{1}{4}\left[\frac{1}{2n\log^2(2n)}-\frac{1}{(2n+2)^2\log^2(2n+2)}\right]$ to get
$$\sum_{k\geq 2}\frac{(-1)^k}{\log k}=\frac{1}{2\log 2}+\frac{1}{8\log^2(2)}+\\+\frac{1}{4}\sum_{n\geq 1}\small{\left[\frac{2}{\log(2n)}-\frac{4}{\log(2n+1)}+\frac{2}{\log(2n+2)}-\frac{1}{2n\log^2(2n)}+\frac{1}{(2n+2)\log^2(2n+2)}\right]}.$$
The main term of the last series behaves like $\frac{1}{n^4\log^2(n)}$. Each term is negative but the very first term is already $\geq -\frac{1}{4}$, hence

$$ S-\left(\frac{1}{2\log 2}+\frac{1}{8\log^2(2)}\right) \in \left(-\frac{1}{10},0\right)$$
and $S\approx 0.9243$.

Comment: But since the series is not absolutely convergent, are we allowed to group its terms pairwise ?

Comment: @GCab: if $\sum_{k\geq 0}g(k)$ is conditionally convergent, it equals $\sum_{n\geq 0}(g(2n)+g(2n+1))$. It is enough to compare the partial sums.

Comment: According to Riemann series theorem, one could get whichever value by rearranging the terms, isn't it ?

Comment: @GCab: of course, but it does not mean that *any* rearrangement leads to a different value. For instance $$\sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{n}=\sum_{m\geq 1}\left(\frac{1}{2m-1}-\frac{1}{2m}\right)=\log(2).$$ We may argue that here we are not really rearranging anything: the partial sums of the second series form a subsequence of the partial sums of the first series.

Comment: Under this premise, it is ok

Comment: So there isn't an exact solution of the sum?

Comment: @KemonoChen An exact form is just one which is not an approximation. Do you want a closed form, integral or something else?

Answer (score 0):

$$\sum _{k=0}^{\infty } \frac{z^k}{\log (k+2)}$$
have a zero near to the Z=0,662
[image]

[image]

fo more values
[image]
have a pole in z=1